# JSON::JWS::VerificationFailed Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, omniauth, openid-connect, gluu

I am developing the Single Sign-on (SSO) feature for a system (using OpenID Connect with a Gluu server as the OP). Details of the system are listed as follows:

```
Programming Language:
Ruby on Rails

Ruby Gem of OpenID Connect:
omniauth-openid-connect (https://github.com/jjbohn/omniauth-openid-connect)

Authorization Endpoint:
/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/authorize

Token Endpoint:
/oxauth/seam/resource/restv1/oxauth/token
```

However, the response (token) from the Gluu server causes a **JSON::JWS::VerificationFailed** exception at the system under development (raised by the Ruby Gem omniauth-openid-connect). Apparently, the default method of the Gluu server in signing the token is not compatible with the expectation of the Ruby Gem.

Anything I have missed (in the configuration of the Gluu server / in the settings of the Ruby Gem).

Answer (score 2):

I just find the solution for my problem.  The setting "discovery" of the Gem must be turned on (by default, it is turned off).